# Django object filter not recognizing related name

Tags: django, django-models

Using Django 1.7

This console log demonstrates the problem.  The 'Positions' related field is not recognized.

```
    x = Person.objects.get(PersonSk=452)

    x.Positions
    <django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x0000000005B4A358>

    x.Associations
    <django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x0000000005AEDC18>

    Person.objects.filter(Associations__isnull=True)
    [lots of peeps]

    Person.objects.filter(Positions__isnull=True)
raise_field_error
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Positions' into field.
```

Here are the model classes for Person, PersonAssociation, and Position.  Why does it work for PersonAssociation but not Position?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PERSON].[Person'
        ordering = ('LastName', 'FirstName')

    PersonSk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    FirstName = CharNullField('First Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    LastName = CharNullField('Last Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    Email = CharNullField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    PhoneWork = CharNullField('Work Phone', max_length=20, blank=True)
    PhoneMobile = CharNullField('Mobile Phone', max_length=20, blank=True)


class PersonAssociation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table ='CLIENT].[PersonAssociation'

    PersonAssociationSk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    Client = models.ForeignKey(Client, db_column='ClientCode', related_name='Associations')
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='PersonSk', related_name='Associations')


class Position(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PERSON].[Position'

    PositionSk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column='PersonSk', related_name='Positions')
    ConsumerClient = models.ForeignKey(Client, db_column='ClientCode', related_name='Positions')
    ProviderClient = models.ForeignKey(Client, db_column='ProviderClientCode', related_name='ProviderPositions', blank=True, null=True)
    Role = models.ForeignKey(ContactRole, db_column='ContactRoleSk', related_name='Positions')
    Facility = models.ForeignKey(Facility, db_column='FacilitySk', blank=True, null=True)
    Notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    StartDate = models.DateField()
    EndDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

As far as I can tell, the related_name field is setup in the same way for both?  I also tried changing the related_name in Position to "Plops", and redid the test with the same result.

Here is another console log that I think better illustrates the problem.  In the Positions models, I have the Role field and Person field configured with the same related name.  So I tried this:

```
ContactRole.Positions
<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor object at 0x00000000060F5DA0>

Person.Positions
<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor object at 0x00000000060F5CC0>

ContactRole.objects.filter(Positions__isnull=True)
[ lots of roles ]

Person.objects.filter(Positions__isnull=True)
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Positions' into field.
```

So it looks like its specifically the filter function that isn't working?

Comment: Just a side note, your individual field names should not be capitalized or camel-cased. Instead, use lowercase values and underscores for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that `Positions` isn't a field, it's a relation. If you want a list of employees with zero positions, you'll need to do an aggregation, and then a filter on that aggregation.

Something like this:

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    positions_count=Count('Positions')
).filter(positions_count=0)
```